# API gateway out of connections because of a slow micro service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, microservices, scale, api-gateway

I have an API gateway `G` which connects with multiple services `S1, S2 ...` and so on.

The traffic pattern is so unique, that at certain times I get a surge of traffic (10M req/min) where everyone is trying to access content from `S1`. So `S1` starts becoming a little slow because of which my gateway `G` starts using up all its socket connections in connecting with `S1` and now can not connect with other services anymore.

Users who are trying to access other services (long tail) such as `S2` which are critical for our business are unable to access them because `G` doesn't have any sockets available.

**Things we tried —**

1. Scaling API gateway:
   This is fine as a temporary fix but it becomes really hard to predict the surge traffic and significantly increases the costs at our end.
2. Increase sockets: We have maxed out this setting on our servers.

Are there any other optimisations or architectural changes we can make to make sure the system responds better.

**UPDATE:**

1. Our stack is primarily Node.js

Comment: Clarification: it sounds like your API Gateway is not what I originally assumed -- [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) -- because it wouldn't run out of sockets.  Is that correct?  If not, what is it?  What software is it running and what functions does it perform in your stack?

Answer (score 2):

This is common issue where one of services is getting more load than other services . You can use cloud pattern called **Bulk Head** at your gateway. In this pattern you basically divide resources (connection pool e.g.) among all the services so not any single service is able to consume all the resources. I am not sure what technical stack your are using so you have to find which library works for you , e.g. DotNet core we use Polly. Another one is Hystrix .

[Bulk Head](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/bulkhead)